# An integral problem why:$\int_a^xf(x)dt = (x-a)f(x) $

Tags: integration

Let $f(x)$ be continuous on $[a,b]$ and $F(x)=\frac{1}{x-a}\int_a^xf(t)dt$

Proof: The functions $F(x)$ and $f(x)$ have the same monotonicity on $(a, b]$.

[The answer is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPn2M.jpg),but I don't know why $\int_a^xf(x)\,dt = (x-a)f(x) $

Comment: Thank you for questioning the problem, but the problem description is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x$ is fixed, then in $\int_a^xf(x)dt$ you integrate over the constant $f(x)$ with respect to $t$. Thus $\int_a^xf(x)dt =f(x) \int_a^x 1 dt=(x-a)f(x).$

Comment: Yes, i got it, thank you for your answer sincerely.

Answer (score 2):

The integrand $f(x)$ is a constant (we're integrating with respect to $t$). And the integral of a constant is equal to the product of that constant with the width of the interval you're integrating over, which is $x-a$.